# Is there a type for ASTs?

Tags: elixir

I am wondering whether there is an Elixir `@type` definition for ASTs? So, when I write a function that returns an AST.

```
@spec example() :: ???
def example do
  quote do
    # ...
  end
end
```

I initially thought that ASTs are always tuples:

```
iex> quote do
...>   @example :A
...> end
{:@, [context: Elixir, imports: [{1, Kernel}]],
 [{:example, [context: Elixir], [:A]}]}
```

But it can also be a simple string:

```
iex> quote do
...>   "Foo"
...> end
"Foo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Macro.t()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#t:t/0) which is an alias for [`Macro.input()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#t:input/0) is the type to denote *AST* (as well as macro input, which is, in turn, *AST* too.)

Answer (score 0):

For what I know,

```
@type ast() ::
  # number literal
  number() |

  # atom literal, including true, false and nil
  atom() |

  # string literal without interpolation
  binary() |

  # list literal
  [ast()] |

  # tuple literal with exact 2 elements
  {ast(), ast()} |

  # tuple literal with size other than 2
  {:"{}", keyword(), [ast()]} |

  # map literal
  {:"%{}", keyword(), [{ast(), ast()}]} |

  # foo(bar, baz)
  {atom(), keyword(), [ast()]} |

  # MyModule.foo(bar, baz)
  {{:., keyword(), [module(), atom()]}, keyword(), [ast()]} |

  # unhygienic variable
  {atom(), keyword(), nil} |

  #hygienic variable
  {atom(), keyword(), module()} |

  # foo.bar
  {{:., keyword(), [ast(), ast()]}, keyword(), []} |

  # a block of code
  {:__block__, keyword(), [ast()]}
```

And I definitely don't know much.

Comment: Atoms representing modules (those started with a capital letter) are represented in _AST_ as `{:__aliases__, metadata(), [atom()]}` fwiw.